# Get Laravel collection's item using collection value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, collections

Suppose we got a collection from the database like this:

```
$projects = Projects::all();
```

Now, for example, I want to get the specific project using the specified column's value. For example, **suppose any project has a unique pr_code, Now I want to get an item of collection that pr_code is 1234.**

**Note = I Know using `Projects::where('pr_code', 1234)->first()` But I didn't want this. I want use inside collection**

How I could do that?

Comment: `$projects = Projects::where('pr_code', 1234)->first();`

Comment: I don't understand your note. Please show an example

Answer (score 2):

Collections also have [where](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-where) and [first](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first) (and [whereFirst](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first-where) ) functions. So you just need to change the order of functions in your chain: `Projects::all()->firstWhere('pr_code', 1234)`

Answer (score 1):

`Projects::all()` queries all records in projects and returns them as a Collection of Projects models, this could be quite a performance hit.

`Projects::where('pr_code', 1234)->get()` will query for the specific projects and return a Collection of Projects models that have pr_code of 1234.

`Projects::where('pr_code', 1234)->first()` will do the same, but return the first as a Projects model.

I recommend naming the model Project rather than the plural Projects. The Laravel model is smart enough to know to use the plural name of the database table.